# linux text film, minus number of one column use other column or add one certain number?

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed

like these two column,

```
   1    2
   2    3
   1    4
```

**1) column2 minus column1**
the result will be

```
1  
1  
3
```

**2) add 10 to column1**
the result will be

```
11  2
12  3
11  4
```

Anyone has ideas about how to realize this two result, prefer by "awk" or "sed"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two...

```
$ awk '{print $2-$1}' file

$ awk '{$1+=10}1' file
```